# Django ImageKit change image dimension inside Admin site

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I use ImageKit to display images inside Django Admin site and it works fine:

```
@admin.register(Client)
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'client_logo', ]

    client_logo = AdminThumbnail(image_field='logo')
    client_logo.short_description = 'Logo'

    readonly_fields = ['client_logo']
```

But I need to display the images as thumbnails not in the original dimension, but I can't figure out how to use processors there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation (https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#admin), I think you can only use `AdminThumbnail` to refer to an existing model field.

Could you use `ImageSpecField` within your `models.py` to generate a smaller version of the logo (https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#defining-specs-in-models)?

```
logo_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='logo',
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(width=150)],
                                format='JPEG')
```

And then just change the reference in `admin.py`:

```
client_logo = AdminThumbnail(image_field='logo_thumbnail')
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to change your model, you'd probably need to manually overwrite the admin templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates